# Docker API - Exec start returns "Page not found"

Tags: api, curl, docker, docker-api

I'm trying to execute a command in a running docker container through the [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/) with `cURL`. I'm following the [instructions in the API doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.29/#tag/Exec).
First I [create an exec instance](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.29/#operation/ContainerExec) and as a response I receive the ID of the created exec. 
Then I use the this ID when I try to [send a request to start](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.29/#operation/ExecStart) this exec, which looks as follows:

```json
$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" -x POST "http:/v1.29/exec/myExecID/start"
```

But the response from that request is:

```json
{"message":"page not found"}
```

This is my Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

In the [code in the Moby's repository](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/d3c780bb90cb5a087fdbffbb8be14fa5eaacca10/client/container_exec.go#L29), they call the absolutely same address.

Anyone else faced this problem ever before? I'll be glad if you share your experience.

Comment: You have http:// localhost in the URL. It looks like you are calling some web server on your host instead of the Docker engine API.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just fixed my question. The problem is that both ways it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it happens because you did not include the request body like this :

```
-d '{"Detach": false, "Tty": false}'
```

If you even get an error like below :

```
{"message":"No such exec instance '<ID>' found in daemon"}
```

That means you have not created an instance for exec. If so, you need to create a new instance

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"AttachStdin": false, "AttachStdout": true, "AttachStderr": true, "DetachKeys": "ctrl-p,ctrl-q", "Tty": false, "Cmd": ["date"], "Env": ["FOO=bar", "BAZ=quux"]}' \
-X POST http:/v1.29/containers/fafe141c1a2b/exec
```

Output (example) :

```
{"Id":"70f08c296d460d2fe254ecd0f8e0416777a6b938bb74a325ffc76405d33d3526"}
```

After that then you can do exec as shown below :

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"Detach": false, "Tty": false}' \
-X POST http:/v1.29/exec/70f08c296d460d2fe254ecd0f8e0416777a6b938bb74a325ffc76405d33d3526/start
```

I've tried that way and it works, hopefully can help!

Comment: Yeah, it was because I didn't include the request body, which I thought that is not required.